# Migrating MongoDB to another server - where can I find the old config?

Tags: mongodb

I've moved our MongoDB to a new server. The developer who originally set it up has since left, and I can't seem to find the original configuration settings.

The 2.6 version I have uses a configuration file in the default installation directory, but I can't seem to find the old one. Is there a query or something I can run to find the original config?

Edit 1: The mongod process is run as a Windows Service, and the arguments are:
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod" --logpath  e:\mongodb\logs  --logappend  --dbpath  "e:\mongodb\data"  --directoryperdb  --service

Edit 2: All the data files in my db have been split into exactly 2,096,128kb files, with the filename pattern of DocumentStore.0, DocumentStore.1, etc. If there is no config file, then how was this specified, or is this just default MongoDB behavior?

Comment: Did you look at `.mongo.rc.js` in your home folder?

Comment: @ma08 That has nothing to do with the server configuration by default. The question really is which operating system was the previous server installed on as that gives a reasonable idea to where the default config file locations are. Or otherwise inspect the process on the old server for the `--config` value.

Comment: @NeilLunn sorry. I thought it had something to do with configuration.

Comment: MongoDB is using no config file, it is using command operators only by your edit

Comment: Edit 2: This is default MongoDB behaviour

Comment: @Sammaye: Thats wrong. The mongod uses config files: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/
So anywhere the file must be.

Comment: @MUmla not in this case, the configuration file has to be specified

Comment: No. when its not specified, the instance uses the config-file at the default path, at linux for example /etc/mongodb.conf. But I don't know how its working under Windows.

Comment: @MUmla Are you certain about that? Have you got a reference?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#configuration
Should be the same when you even not use a replicaset.

Comment: @MUmla I beleive it says that because that is where the default apt-get installer for mongodb infact places its configuration however I have raised an issue in the google user group to get to the bottom of it

Comment: @MUmla as ou can see in the introduction by it pointing you to the installation tutorials which in turn point to installing by apt-get http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/#requirements

Comment: @MUmla https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/Dn9_cJDChgs there is no default configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer both of your edits.

First by the command line you are using:

```
 "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod" --logpath e:\mongodb\logs --logappend --dbpath "e:\mongodb\data" --directoryperdb --service
```

MongoDB is in fact not using a configuration file. In order for MongoDB to use a configuration file it has to have the command option --config/-f specified. You do not have that as such MongoDB in this case is using no configuration file.

Even on linux the default install of MongoDB (through apt-get) is to specify a configuration file, normally in `/etc/` and will reference an `init.d` script with the command `mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf`.

Hence whenever you install from packages you will have a default configuration path, however, it has to actually be supplied which yours is not.

As such you have no configuration file, all of your options are passed straight into the command.

As for your second edit, all of this is default under MongoDB, that is how it works.

Comment: Sammaye is correct. I was browsing the MongoDB docs and came across a page which specifically mentions the 2gb split per file. From what I can tell, this behavior isn't even configurable (but you can change the chunk split size, I think).

Comment: @drminnaar indeed, you can change how chunks will be split in a sharded envo however, I have rarely, if ever, touched that setting. It is almost never needed

Answer (score 0):

When the config file isn't in the default directory, the instance of mongod should have been started wtih the parameter `--config [location]`. Is your old instance of mongod still running? And do you have access to an shell of the server? Then run `ps aux | grep mongod` and behind the command could (should?) possibly be the parameter with the location.

Comment: A windows service is used for the mongod process - see my edited question.
As for the ps command - I'm getting an error 'the term 'grep' is not recognized'...

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought you were running it on a linux machine. Than grep won't work.
But nevertheless you have the arguments, good. Hm. That doesn't helps us in this case :( Nothing with --config.

Comment: See my Edit 2 - does this rule out a config?

Comment: see @sammaye 's comment under your question.